# How to add IDs of a checkbox in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I am working on a school project where a user can choose what items he/she can borrow from the school's computer services office. I have completed the application form where the student/faculty can insert their profile information. I am having issues regarding the checkboxes in AngularJS.

I need to total/sum up the IDs of the checkboxes so that it can be inserted into the database as a single int, not an array. Here are the code and some information.

```js
        $scope.chkItems = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Laptop',
            value: null,

        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Headset',
            value: null
        }, {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Projector',
            value: null
        }, {
            id: 8,
            name: 'Tablet',
            value: null
        }, {
            id: 16,
            name: 'Speakers',
            value: null
        }];



$scope.save = function () {

                var chkItemsValue = '';

                $scope.chkItems.forEach(function (Item) {

                    if (Item.value) {
                        chkItemValue +=  chkItem.id;
                    }
                })   
                
                }
```

```html
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
<label class="force-input-label">Items</label>
</br>
<div ng-repeat="chkItem in chkItems">
<md-checkbox name="chkItem.name" ng-model="chkItem.value" ng-true-value=1 ng-false-value=0>{{chkItem.name}}
</div>
</md-input-container>
```

I can insert the value on the database but the value is different instead of getting the total the value I get an array like output.

- Currently, I am getting this:

if I check {Laptop, Projector, Speakers}
the total would be 1416

- What I want:

if I check {Laptop, Projector, Speakers}
the total would be 21

I am new to AngularJS and web development. Your inputs are greatly appreciated!

ThankYOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer, don't initialise your counter as a string

```
var chkItemsValue = 0 // not ''
```

---

[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) answer

```
var chkItemsValue = $scope.chkItems.reduce((count, item) => {
    return count + (item.value ? item.id : 0)
}, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. : )

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. : )
WOW. it took me days to check on this one. And i checked my old code the chkItemsValue is set to zero. Maybe it was change when i use find and  replace.

THANKS A LOT. This matter has already been resolved thankyou!